# Is it possible to write a Windows 10 script opening speaker settings?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I want to write a windows 10 batch script to change my microphone's output volume, as Skype apparently is not able to provide me with consistent settings. Can you point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To change the `volume` You can build 2 vbs files :

soundown.vbs

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys  "{" & chr(174) & " 5}"
```

soundup.vbs

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys  "{" & chr(175) & " 20}"
```

and then call them from your `.bat`file :

```
@echo off

cscript.exe /nologo soundown.vbs
```

or the same with `soundup.vbs`

**EDIT:**

You can modify the steps it will  modify the volume by modifing the value 5 and 20 in the `VBS`files

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply! I actually want to adjust my *microphone* output volume, i.e. the volume used to record with the mic. Aren't the vbs commands above related to the *speaker's* volume?
To be perfectly clear, here's the UI routine I would like to script:
1. Go to Sound
2. Select the Input tab (the 2dn one)
3. Open my built-in microphone
4. Select the Levels tab.
5. Adjust the 'enhance volume' slider (the 2dn one) from '0' to '10'.